# .glb file doesn't show in express server

Tags: node.js, express, aframe

I want to run a simple webserver that shows a .glb file in VR using a-frame.

When I use the "Open in Default Browser" extension in vs code the html below shows without problems, both box and file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hello, WebVR! • A-Frame</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Hello, WebVR! • A-Frame">
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.3.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene background="color: #ECECEC">
      <a-gltf-model position="4 -10 -100" rotation="210 0 0" src="/EPE_4.glb" shadow="receive: true"></a-gltf-model>
      <a-box position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0" color="#4CC3D9" shadow></a-box>
      <a-plane position="0 0 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4" shadow></a-plane>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, when I run a server providing the html using Express, with the node command, only the box and plane is visible. Note that the .glb is somewhat large at 200 MB.

Below is my app.js and package.js file.

Thank you in advance for any help.

app.js

```
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/index.html'));
});

app.use('/', router);
app.listen(process.env.port || 3000);

console.log('Running at Port 3000');
```

package.js

```
{
  "name": "vr_test2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "devstart": "SET DEBUG=vr_test:* & nodemon ./bin/www"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: any console errors?

Comment: There were none in PowerShell

Comment: and the browser?

Comment: To begin with thank you for helping me find leads.
The browser console had the following:
```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)   :3000/EPE_4.glb:1
```
Which means it fails to load resource, it's curious that it succeeds with the vs plugin but not with express running.

Where could I begin to look to solve this?

Comment: I guess You're trying to load the resource at the [root level](http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/difference-between-absolute-and-relative-path/#:~:text=In%20simple%20words%2C%20an%20absolute,directory%20you%20are%20working%20on.). Try `./EPE_4.glb` with a dot

Comment: Adding a public folder and serving the file via "app.use(express.static('public'))" has made the epe model show. But I'm unsure if the model becomes available for anyone to download or not (unwanted behaviour)? The file doesn't show in sources, does that mean it's safe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone has a similar problem.
Check the browser's console log, mine showed that the webpage couldn't find the .glb file.
I solved this by adding a public folder and serving it to the client by using:

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```